# Predict a 2D matrix from an image with keras keeping spatial information

Tags: neural-network, keras

I want to train a CNN to predict `100x100x1` matrices (heatmaps) from `224x224x13` images using Keras. My idea is to finetune pretrained networks that keras provide (resnet, Xception, vgg16 etc.).

The first step is then to substitute the pretrained top layers for the ones that meet my problem constraints. I am trying to predict `100x100x1` heatmap images whose values range from 0 to 1. Therefore I want the output of my network to be a `100x100x1` matrix. I believe that if I use `Flatten` and then a `Dense` layer of `1000x1x1` I will be loosing spatial information, which I don't want (right?).

I want my code to be flexible, to be able to run independent from which pretrained architecture is being used (I have to run many experiments). Therefore I want to stack a `Dense` layer that connects to every unit of whatever kind of layer is before it (which will depend on the pretrained architecture I will be using).

Some answers relate to the fully convolutional approach, but that is not what I mean here. Both my `X` and `Y` have fixed shapes (`224x224x3` and `100x100x1` respectively).

My problem is that I don't now how to stack the new layer/s in such a way that the predictions/outputs of the net are `100x100x1` matrices.
As it has been suggested in the answers, I am trying to add a `100x100x1` `Dense` layer. But I don't seem to get it working:
If for example I to like this:

```
x = self.base_model.output
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(input_shape = (None, 100,100), units= 1000, activation='linear')(x)
self.model = keras.models.Model(input=self.base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

Then I got this when I start training:

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 100, 100)`

The `Y` of the network are indeed batches of shape `(64,100,100)`
Any suggestions?

Also, which loss function should I use? As it has been suggested in the answers, I could use `mse` but I wonder, is there any loss function that is able to measure the spatial information of my desired `100x100x1` output?

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT:

I **semi-solved** my problem thanks to @ncasas answer:

I just added some deconvolutional layers until I got an output that was similar to the `100x100x1`. This is not what I wanted on the first place, since this implementation is not agnostic to the pretrained architecture that is built on top of. For `Xception` with `input_shape = (224, 224, 3)`, this top layers give an output of `80x80x1`:

```
x = self.base_model.output
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((3, 3))(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
predictions = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 1,
                                 kernel_size = (3, 3),
                                 activation='sigmoid',
                                 padding='same')(x)
self.model = keras.models.Model(input=self.base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

where `self.base_model` is `keras.applications.Xception(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False, input_shape = (224, 224, 3))`

I am finally using `mse` as loss function and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a multidimiensional linear regression plus transfer learning.

In order to reuse the first layers of a trained Keras model, you can follow [this post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) from the Keras blog, in section "Using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network: 90% accuracy in a minute". For your case, the only difference is that:

1. For the layer before the last one, you should probably have something larger than 256.
2. The last layer would be a 10000 units Dense layer with linear activations (i.e. no activation at all). You can either reshape your expected outputs from 100x100 to 100000, or add an extra reshape layer to the network to have a 100x100 output.

Keep in mind that between the *convolutional* part of the network and the multilayer perceptron part (i.e. the final Dense layer(s)) there must be a `Flatten` layer to place the obtain activation patterns in a single matrix (search the linked post for "Flatten"); the error you receive is because of that.

If you don't want to flatten the activation patterns, you may want to directly use [deconvolutions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) in your last layers. For that, you can take a look at the [keras autoencoder tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), at section "Convolutional autoencoder".

The usual loss function used for regression problems is mean squared error (MSE). It does not make sense to use cross entropy for regression, as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223263/40048).

Comment: why `mean_squared_error` and not `categorical_crosentropy`? thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to add that 100x100 Dense layer (I have updated my question with some some issue related with it)?

Comment: The `unints` parameter is the number of neuron of the `Dense` layer. If I use a `Flatten` I would loose spatial information, which I don't want. How do you define a "100x100x1 Dense layer"?

Comment: Sorry, I had never seen the size of the layer been passed as named parameter, always used it as `Dense(200)` and I didn't know its name. I have clarified that part and added an example of how not to flatten.

Answer (score 2):

You should find [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) helpful. Simply replace the fully connected layers with convolutional layers. Instead of a single prediction for the entire image, the result will be a heatmap of predictions for smaller portions of the image.

[image]

You should use the categorical_crossentropy loss function.

Comment: why `categorical_crossentropy` and not `mean_squared_error`? thanks